# file system uid and gid in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, users

I came across a linux kernel [tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/tlk.html) and there they talked about 4 pairs  of identifiers and one of them was ***file system uid and gid.***

Could someone explain me what it is and how it is different from ***uid and gid***?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Who would have thought that this question would drag out such a collection of overconfident and underinformed responses!

The ***file system uid*** or ***fsuid*** is a Linux feature designed to help the NFS server implementation. It is an extra (non-POSIX) uid which is used only for file permission checks. For any process that doesn't call `setfsuid` (basically any process that's not trying to be an NFS server), the fsuid is the same as the effective uid.

There's even a [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setfsuid.2.html) for it, so excuse for claiming it doesn't exist.

**Update**: I was inspired to go find the origin of fsuid. When it was added in Linux 1.1.44, this comment was put above the new `sys_setfsuid` function:

```
+/*
+ * "setfsuid()" sets the fsuid - the uid used for filesystem checks. This
+ * is used for "access()" and for the NFS daemon (letting nfsd stay at
+ * whatever uid it wants to). It normally shadows "euid", except when
+ * explicitly set by setfsuid() or for access..
+ */
```

and this change was made in the comment above `sys_access`:

```
- * XXX we should use the real ids for checking _all_ components of the
- * path.  Now we only use them for the final component of the path.
+ * access() needs to use the real uid/gid, not the effective uid/gid.
+ * We do this by temporarily setting fsuid/fsgid to the wanted values
```

So NFS was one of the original two purposes. The other was making `access` work correctly. `access` is used by setuid programs to determine whether the real user would have access to a file without the additional privileges of the setuid. Before 1.1.44 it was buggy. Since then, it's been using a temporary change of fsuid to do the work. Since the fsuid is restored before the `access` system call returns, you'll never actually see the change from userspace.