# Is Linux the only operating system in the Unix-like/Unix category of operating systems that uses the "fsuid" and the "fsgid"?

Tags: linux, osx, solaris, bsd

Linux uses the file system user id (`fsuid`) instead of the effective user ID (`euid`), and the file system group ID (`fsgid`) instead of the effective group ID (`egid`) in permission checks.

Is Linux the only operating system in the Unix-like/Unix category of operating systems that uses the `fsuid` and the `fsgid`? for example, do operating systems like BSD, macOS, Solaris use the `fsuid` and the `fsgid`?

Comment: Related but not a duplicate - [file system uid and gid in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45860/file-system-uid-and-gid-in-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All mentions of the `fsuid` I can find seem to say "Linux only" or something to that effect.

The [man page `setfsuid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setfsuid.2.html):

> `setfsuid()` is Linux-specific and should not be used in programs
>          intended to be portable.

This [comparison on UID setting functions](http://unixpapa.com/incnote/setuid.html) of different Unixes:

> `setfsuid(uid)`
>   Sets the process's filesystem UID to a new value. [...]
>   Linux only.

As noted by the man page, the `fsuid` was only used to work around a potential issue with (userspace) NFS servers and the signal handling rules  in old versions of Linux; it's not likely to be used much any more.